# casting of string to double

Tags: android, string, casting, double, android-edittext

I have made a simple android app,i that some calculations are there from 1 activity's EditText value some multiplication,sum and other mathematical procedures and showing results as double in another activities edittexs.so can anyone please tell me is it necessary to cast string value to "double" for making calculation and how can i do it?

**Activity1.java**

```
Intent ic = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this,Calculator2a.class);
        ic.putExtra("e1", et1.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e2", et2.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e3", et3.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e4", et4.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e5", et5.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e6", et6.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e7", et7.getText().toString());
        ic.putExtra("e8", et8.getText().toString());

        startActivity(ic);
```

and i fetch its values in activity2a,but can't do calculations....pls help..:(

**Activity2a.java**

```
  Intent receiveIntent = this.getIntent();
        String etz1 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e1");
        String etz2 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e2");
        String etz3 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e3");
        String etz4 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e4");
        String etz5 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e5");
        String etz6 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e6");
        String etz7 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e7");
        String etz8 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e8");

        et1.setText(etz1);
        et2.setText(etz2);
        et3.setText(etz3);
        et4.setText(etz4);
        et5.setText(etz5);
        et6.setText(etz6);
        et7.setText(etz7);
        et8.setText(etz8);
```

please help me

Comment: What is your real problem

Comment: my frend i just want to cast editText value to double...so that i can do calculation.

Comment: just take the value to double by adding cast.After your calculation reverse it

Comment: @jimmycool : what u have tried to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like below

```
        Intent receiveIntent = this.getIntent();
        String etz1 = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("e1");

        double erz1Double = Double.parseDouble(etz1); //converting into double
      // follow same for all the string values, dont forget to add try Catch for number formatException, and null check for string values
```

**Edit:-**  for casting double to string, there are many ways can do something like below

```
 String erz1String = erz1Double + "";

       or


 String erz1String = String.valueOf(erz1Double);
```

Comment: how to cast again double to string...because the result also have to show in "EditText"..so if any other way..?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert String to Double to make calculations you can do it like that :

```
String myStringValue = "15.432";
double value = Double.parseDouble(myStringValue);
```

In your case you can do this :

```
intent.putExtra("myKey", Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString()));
```

And last thing, you can get double directly from your intent using this :

```
double myValue = 1.00;
try {
     myValue = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("myKey", 1.00);
catch(NumberFormatException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No need to get it as string and than convert to double, if you need that.

**Edit:**  As I understand you want to get value from EditText as double, make some calculations and than send them/it to Activity2 and show the result in another `EditText`. If that's the correct scenario first of all you can force the user to type only numeric values because you will need to make calculations with them. You can convert your string to double as I mentioned above. After that just send your values using `putExtra();`, get them in your second activity and set as text in your second `EditText`.

Comment: if OP use this code inside try/catch block then it's good to avoid numberformatexception exception and assign default value

Comment: It depends on the situation, but in my opinion it's good to validate first the user's input and let him type only numeric value.Of course in case that I need only numbers. But yeah, good point on catching NumberFormatException.

Comment: but the value entered in Edittext of Activity1 will be in string...so...through intent "getStringExtra" only can be used...rite?

Comment: So what kind of input you need, only numeric or whatever user's type in your EditText?

Comment: brothr i do some calculation on that values and then want to show it in another activity's EditText..so can you please tell me how can it b?

Answer (score 1):

This is required to cast a String to double:

```
String myStringValue = "30.00";
double value = Double.parseDouble(myStringValue);
```